# How to get combinations of keys for an object, based on a single different value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

I created a product schema in mongodb with variants for the same product. For example, take a phone, something like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"65d881d4d080a591933b1be2"},
"title":"Iphone 15",
"category":{"$oid":"65d881b1831df3b991251f56"},
"brand":"Apple",
"properties":{"memory":["64GB","128GB","256GB"],"color":["black","white"]},
"price":{"$numberLong":"1200"}, 
"variants":[
{"title":"Iphone 15 64GB black","SKU":"1123-1231-45lsaph15","price":{"$numberLong":"1200"},"properties":{"memory":"64GB","color":"black"},"stock":{"$numberLong":"24"}},
{"title":"Iphone 15 128GB black","SKU":"1123-1231-75lsaph15","price":{"$numberLong":"1300"},"properties":{"memory":"128GB","color":"black"},"stock":{"$numberLong":"10"}},
{"title":"Iphone 15 64GB white","SKU":"1123-1231-46lsaph15","price":{"$numberLong":"1200"},"properties":{"memory":"64GB","color":"white"},"stock":{"$numberLong":"20"}},
{"title":"Iphone 15 128GB white","SKU":"1123-1231-76lsaph15","price":{"$numberLong":"1350"},"properties":{"memory":"128GB","color":"white"},"stock":{"$numberLong":"17"}}]}
```

i retrieve this product like this:

```
  const wholeProductData: any = await fetchSingleProduct(id);
  
  const variant = wholeProductData.variants.find((v: any) => v.SKU === params.id);
```

let's say that now our product is the black one with 64gb:

```
{
  title: 'Iphone 15 64GB black',
  SKU: '1123-1231-45lsaph15',
  price: 1200,
  properties: { memory: '64GB', color: 'black' },
  stock: 24
}
```

my question is, for this object, how can I retrieve/filter the related variants? i.e. for each property key, to get the variants that only have that property key different.
this is what I mean:
for `color` i want to find the variants that have the other properties the same (`memory: '64gb'`) but other values for `color` (i.e. white). Something like iterating for only one property key

**example:**
Initial list with variants:

```
[
{
    title: 'Iphone 15 64GB black',
    SKU: '1123-1231-45lsaph15',
    price: 1200,
    properties: { memory: '64GB', color: 'black' },
    stock: 24
  },
  {
    title: 'Iphone 15 128GB black',
    SKU: '1123-1231-75lsaph15',
    price: 1300,
    properties: { memory: '128GB', color: 'black' },
    stock: 10
  },
{
    title: 'Iphone 15 64gb white',
    SKU: '1123-1231-46lsaph15',
    price: 1300,
    properties: { memory: '64GB', color: 'white' },
    stock: 10
  },
{
    title: 'Iphone 15 128gb white',
    SKU: '1123-1231-76lsaph15',
    price: 1300,
    properties: { memory: '128GB', color: 'white' },
    stock: 10
  },
]
```

desired result:

```
color:
 [ {
    title: 'Iphone 15 64gb white',
    SKU: '1123-1231-46lsaph15',
    price: 1300,
    properties: { memory: '64GB', color: 'white' },
    stock: 10
  },
{
    title: 'Iphone 15 64GB black',
    SKU: '1123-1231-45lsaph15',
    price: 1200,
    properties: { memory: '64GB', color: 'black' },
    stock: 24
  }
]

memory: 
[
{
    title: 'Iphone 15 64GB black',
    SKU: '1123-1231-45lsaph15',
    price: 1200,
    properties: { memory: '64GB', color: 'black' },
    stock: 24
  },
  {
    title: 'Iphone 15 128GB black',
    SKU: '1123-1231-75lsaph15',
    price: 1300,
    properties: { memory: '128GB', color: 'black' },
    stock: 10
  },
]
```

**EDIT1:**

Temporary solution with result to get a better understanding of the desired result:

https://playcode.io/1774782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what your intention is because your desired results don't exactly correlate to what you describe.

Nevertheless, you can use [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for this purpose instead of `find` and then having to `filter` programatically. I think you can use this example below to best suit your needs:

1. `$match` - find a document with `variants.SKU` equal to `1123-1231-45lsaph15`. This can of course be a parameter from `req.params`.
2. `$set` an independent property called `source` which is the value of the matching object. We will use this as the source document to do our filter comparisons.
3. `$unwind`a simple stage to turn the `source` into an object from an array.
4. `$project` - this will set 3 new properties.
5. `sameMemory` - `$filter` the `variants` array and only return objects that have a `memory` ***equal*** to the `source` object `memory`.
6. `differentColor` - `$filter` the `variants` array and only return objects that have a `color` ***not equal*** to the `source` object `color`.
7. `sameMemoryButDifferentColor` - `$filter` the `variants` array and only return objects that have a `memory` ***equal*** to the `source` object `memory` ***and*** a `color` ***not equal*** to the `source` object `color`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "variants.SKU": "1123-1231-45lsaph15"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      source: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$variants",
          as: "v",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$v.SKU",
              "1123-1231-45lsaph15"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$source"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      sameMemory: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$variants",
          as: "v",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$v.properties.memory",
              "$source.properties.memory"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      differentColor: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$variants",
          as: "v",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$v.properties.color",
              "$source.properties.color"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      sameMemoryButDifferentColor: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$variants",
          as: "v",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$v.properties.memory",
                  "$source.properties.memory"
                ]
              },
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$$v.properties.color",
                  "$source.properties.color"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      source: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AtKMl6cqmz2) for a working example.

Comment: This is a great way to work directly on the database, didn't think about it. I also came up with a solution to do it programatically, [check here](https://playcode.io/1774782) to also get a better understanding of what I mean

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. So you want to step over each of the matching objects `properties` key/value pairs no matter how many there are and filter that way?

Comment: Yes, you can see it like a combination problem with fixed values and only one changing property. I couldn't find any _elegant_ way of doing it. It is somewhat tricky because the properties are not something stable, (i.e. color, memory) for some other products could be totally different (eg: material, size), as the administrator creates his own products/categories

Comment: You can use aggregation to turn the properties of the matching object into an array of key/value pairs and then map over them one by one to do the filter but it gets quite complicated and sometimes complex aggregations can be impossible to read 6 months later. I'll take a look.

Comment: Something [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8GDS2nl5sfy) would get you the same results where you are stepping over the properties as distinct key/value pair objects and seeing if that key/value pair object is `$in` the any of the variants properties.

Comment: That's a really good solution. You're really good with it. I'll just have to think which way would be easier to read/maintain/modify in future regarding this. The js temporary solution that I provided, can also be challenging if you don't look into it frequently or for a new eye.

Comment: If you have alot of variations to loop through then I would use the aggregate query as it is asynchronous whereas the for loop is synchronous in Node (blocking). You would need to write an asynchronous function to work around that.